# необходимо вывести данные о свободных номерах в гостинице на определенные даты средствами transact-sql

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Срочно нужна помощь.
Запрос должен создаваться на языке t-sql, на основе 3-х таблиц:
бронирование (из таблицы берутся id номера и даты заезда и отъезда в/из него (check_in_date и eviction_date соответственно))

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[booking](
    [id] [int] PRIMARY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [client_id] [int] NULL,
    [room_id] [int] NULL,
    [check_in_date] [date] NULL,
    [eviction_date] [date] NULL,
    [booking_cost] [decimal](19, 2) NULL
)
```

Таблица номеров отеля в запросе связывает таблицу бронирование с типами номеров

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[hotel_room](
    [id] [int] PRIMARY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [type_id] [int] NULL,
    [number_on_door] [int] NULL
)
```

Из таблицы типы номеров выводится вся информация о типе если в таблице hotel_room есть хотя бы один номер с hotel_room.type_id=room_type.id, для которого в таблице booking нет записи для которых указанные при вызове процедуры даты не пересекаются с датами бронирование

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[room_type](
    [id] [int] PRIMARY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [decryption] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [description] [text] NULL,
    [max_number_guest] [int] NOT NULL,
    [price] [decimal](19, 2) NULL,
    [refund_upon_booking_cancel] [bit] NULL,
    [photo] [varchar](30) NOT NULL
)
```

Создаю такую процедуру, но он не работает:

```
Create Procedure available_rooms
@check_date date,
@eviction date,
@guest int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @D date;
SET @D = @check_date;
DECLARE @interval table (date_on_interval date);
WHILE @D <= @eviction
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @interval(date_on_interval) VALUES (@D);
SET @D = DATEADD(day, 1, @D);
END;
SELECT COUNT(hotel_room.type_id), room_type.id, room_type.name, room_type.decryption, room_type.description, room_type.max_number_guest, room_type.price, room_type.refund_upon_booking_cancel, room_type.photo FROM hotel_room INNER JOIN room_type ON hotel_room.type_id=room_type.id INNER JOIN booking ON booking.room_id=hotel_room.id WHERE booking.check_in_date NOT IN (SELECT * FROM @interval) AND booking.eviction_date NOT IN (SELECT * FROM @interval) GROUP BY room_type.id;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте так: ищем количество свободных на этот период комнат в разрезе типов и выводим это количество с описанием типа

```
DECLARE @check_date DATE,
    @eviction   DATE


SELECT t.name,
    t.decryption,
    t.max_number_guest,
    t.price,
    t.refund_upon_booking_cancel,
    t.photo,
    x.RoomsCount
FROM dbo.room_type t
    JOIN (
        SELECT r.type_id, COUNT(r.id) AS RoomsCount
        FROM dbo.hotel_room r
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.booking
            WHERE room_id = r.id
                AND (
                    @check_date BETWEEN check_in_date AND eviction_date
                    OR @eviction BETWEEN check_in_date AND eviction_date
                    OR check_in_date BETWEEN @check_date AND @eviction
                )
        )
        GROUP BY r.type_id
    ) x ON x.type_id = t.id
```